# Ubuntu 16.4.1 amd64 Stop Working While ShutingDown

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

> I'm Using Windows 10 And Try To Have Ubuntu Alongside It,

I have A Problem With 3 Linux Versions (linux mint, ubuntu 16.4.1, ubuntu 18),
But I Had The Same Problem That The Operating System Stop Working And Not Responding Every Time I Try To Shut Down , Everything Is Hide But The Background Still,
I Found Some Solutions But It Wasn't Work Too,
Like Edite `/etc/default/grub` Line :

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

To :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
```

And Run `update-grub` But It Didn't Work To

Comment: Just to clarify, are you able to successfully boot into both Ubuntu and Windows? But the problem is that you can't shut down Ubuntu without the system freezing?

Comment: I Followed An Online Tutorial To Install Ubuntu Along Side Windows 10, And All Is Fine And Working But The Problem Is The System Is Freezing Every Time I Try To Turn Off, So I Had To Turn off Using The Power Button